# How call Oracle stored procedure using EclipseLink (JPA)

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, eclipselink

could somebody explain me how call stored procedure using EclipseLink? 
Here is my  stored procedure:

```
TYPE nested_varchar2 IS TABLE OF varchar2(15);
TYPE nested_number IS TABLE OF number(1);

 procedure set_pacs_state_cond(
    icond in varchar2, -- where condition
    icheck_state in number, -- check expected current state
    iso_id_list out nested_varchar2, -- list of suboperators
    ipac_list out nested_varchar2, -- list of pacs
    iresult out nested_number -- list of results
);
```

I'm using EclipseLink 2.4.1 as JPA implementation. Please see my code below.

```
PLSQLStoredProcedureCall call = new PLSQLStoredProcedureCall();

call.setProcedureName("PCK_PR.set_pacs_state_cond");

call.addNamedArgument("icond", "icond", Types.VARCHAR);
call.addNamedArgument("icheck_state", "icheck_state", Types.NUMERIC);
call.addNamedOutputArgument("iso_id_list", "iso_id_list", Types.ARRAY, "nested_varchar2");
call.addNamedOutputArgument("ipac_list", "ipac_list", Types.ARRAY, "nested_varchar2");
call.addNamedOutputArgument("iresult","iresult", Types.ARRAY, "nested_number");

DataModifyQuery valQuery = new DataModifyQuery();
valQuery.setCall(call);

valQuery.addArgument("icond");
valQuery.addArgument("icheck_state");
valQuery.addArgument("iso_id_list", java.sql.Array.class);
valQuery.addArgument("ipac_list", java.sql.Array.class);
valQuery.addArgument("iresult", java.sql.Array.class);

List test1 = new ArrayList();
List test2 = new ArrayList();
List test3 = new ArrayList();

valQuery.addArgumentValue("WHERE");
valQuery.addArgumentValue(1);
valQuery.addArgumentValue(test1);
valQuery.addArgumentValue(test2);
valQuery.addArgumentValue(test3);

session.executeQuery(valQuery);

List results = (List) session.executeQuery(valQuery);

em.getTransaction().commit();

DatabaseRecord record = (DatabaseRecord)results.get(0);

List ii = (List) record.get("iso_id_list");
List i = (List) record.get("ipac_list");
List r = (List) record.get("iresult");

em.close();
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 5, column 21:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ARRAY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 21:
```

Answer (score 3):

PLSQL TABLE types cannot be returned through JDBC.  The way PLSQLStoredProcedureCall works is it wraps the TABLE types with VARRAY types.  You need to create the mirror VARRAY types yourslef, and specify them.  Here is an example of one of or tests,

```
    PLSQLCollection collection = new PLSQLCollection();
    collection.setTypeName("PLSQL_P.PLSQL_CITY_LIST");
    collection.setCompatibleType("PLSQL_P_PLSQL_CITY_LIST");
    collection.setNestedType(JDBCTypes.VARCHAR_TYPE);

    PLSQLStoredProcedureCall call = new PLSQLStoredProcedureCall();
    call.setProcedureName("PLSQL_P.PLSQL_CITY_LIST_IN");
    call.addNamedArgument("P_CITY_LIST", collection);
    call.addNamedArgument("P_CITY", JDBCTypes.VARCHAR_TYPE);
    DataModifyQuery query = new DataModifyQuery();
    query.addArgument("P_CITY_LIST", java.sql.Array.class);
    query.addArgument("P_CITY", String.class);
    query.setCall(call);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for fast answer ! I will try and let you know !! Thanks !

Comment: James, could you provide definition of your stored procedure and types, please? thanks!

Comment: But as far I know, when you define VARRAY, you need to specify fix length, right? I don't know length in design time. Can I handle it somehow?

Comment: You could just give a sufficiently large size, I think you can also use a nested table type.

Comment: I have this error doing that : Adding named arguments without DatabaseType classification to PLSQLStoredProcedureCall is not supported